# Dynamic form addition/subtraction with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to get my dynamic form additions/subtractions to work correctly. The situation is that I am able to get the form block to add or remove, however, when I click the remove button it removes the most recently added block rather than the one I click on.

For example, if I add two new form blocks for a total of 3 blocks (block1, block2, block3) and I click remove on block2, instead of removing block 2 it removes block3.

I have created a plunker that demonstrates this, but it ONLY works when you launch the preview side in a separate window (otherwise the add button is inactive for some reason).

Working Example (must open in popup preview in plunker to function): [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JhOQBAycKPlQl1ypJZBe?p=preview)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="cpdForm" novalidate="" ng-submit="processForm()" ng-show="!message">
  <h2>Subcontractor Performance</h2>
  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat="subcontractor in subcontractors">
    <div class="well well-sm">Subcontractor #{{subcontractor.id}}                            <span id="subCounter"></span>
      <button type="button" ng-click="removeSub()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="subName">Subcontractor Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subName" name="subName" placeholder="Subcontractor" ng-model="formData.subName['subName'+($index+1)]" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="mwbeCert">Disadvantaged Certification</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="mwbeCert" ng-model="formData.mwbeCert" required="">
          <option value="">Select MWBE Certification...</option>
          <option ng-repeat="item in dropdownpoll['mwbecert']" value="{{item.mwbeid}}">{{item.mwbe}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="subAmount">Contracted Amount</label>
        <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subAmount" name="subAmount" placeholder="Contracted Amount" ng-model="formData.subAmount" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="subContactName">Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subContactName" name="subContactName" placeholder="Contact Name" ng-model="formData.subContactName" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="subContactPhone">Contact Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subContactPhone" name="subContactPhone" placeholder="Contact Phone" ng-model="formData.subContactPhone" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="subContactEmail">Contact Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subContactEmail" name="subContactEmail" placeholder="Contact Email" ng-model="formData.subContactEmail" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="subRating">Subcontractor Rating</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="subRating" ng-model="formData.subRating" required="">
          <option value="">Select Subcontractor Rating...</option>
          <option ng-repeat="item in dropdownpoll['subrating']" value="{{item.subratingid}}">{{item.rating}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <label for="subComment">Comments</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subComment" name="subComment" placeholder="Comments" ng-model="formData.subComment" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" ng-show="showAddSub(subcontractor)" ng-click="addNewSub()">[+] Add New Sub</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" style="display:none;" ng-model="formData.subCount" value="{{subcontractor.id}}" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" ng-click="submitting()" ng-disabled="buttonDisabled">{{submit}}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<pre>{{formData}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are splicing `$scope.subcontractors-1` which only behaves like it does, ie, removes the last one.

try using `$event.currentTarget` as a general rule, it will indicate the clicked item exactly, and don't forget to pass `$event` as a parameter for the remove function.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an index to the function removeSub

I modified your fn to accept an index

```
$scope.removeSub = function(ind) {
  var newItemNo = $scope.subcontractors.length-1;
  $scope.subcontractors.splice(ind-1, 1);
};
```

and in your HTML you just pass the currently iterated `$index`

```
<button type="button" ng-click="removeSub($index)" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
</button>
```

Hope this works. But be careful your formdata and subcontrators array are not in sync after this, thats  a programming logic I guess you have to fix.

Happy coding

Cheers.

Joy

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but your not telling the function in your script.js which one to remove your just telling it to chop one off the end. Try setting it up so that you pass the current subContractor id like ng-click="removeSub({{subcontractor.subContractorId}})" (not sure what your data model is) you could also reference the index but I believe that would be harder.